# Why does it print 12345 not 01234?

Tags: java, for-loop

It has to be output like this 01234

```
for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++, System.out.print(i));
```

or

```
for(int i = 0;i < 5; System.out.print(i))
    i++;
```

Output: 12345

Comment: Because `i++` increments `i`. The value is printed after it has been incremented

Comment: in `i++, System.out.print(i)` the printing is executed after the increment (left-to-right) || second loop: the third part of `for` is executed after each iteration, that is, after the block is executed  || both loops: very strange to have the print statement inside the `for` Details: [JLS 14.14.1. The basic for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1)

Comment: https://tenor.com/view/dead-dead-giveaway-obvious-obviously-gif-5930220

Comment: I hope this is just an exercise and not code you mean to use for anything serious. Using `for` loops like this gives no advantage whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0;i < 5; System.out.print(i))
    i++;
```

Is equivalent to the following while loop:

```
{
  int i = 0;
  while (i < 5) {
    i += 1;
    System.out.print(i);
  }
}
```

`i` is always incremented before it is printed. Same goes for `i++, System.out.print(i)`: `i` is already incremented before it is printed. And I don't need to mention that 0 + 1 = 1.

Comment: OP should've known that the fact that 5 was printed and the loop ends at `i < 5` should've been a deeeaaaaaaaad giveaway that the value of `i` was printed after the variable was incremented..... DEAAAAAD GIVEAWAY!!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy, you just need to understand what you're writing.
It should go like:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ //"i" is increased at the end of the loop
    System.out.print(i) //prints "i", which is zero and will increase up to 4
}
```

And that's it